# LibGDX - Scale everything down by 32 using viewport

Tags: java, libgdx

Ok. I need to use box2d for physics in my game but it would take FOREVER to scale everything down to a pixel per meter. Is it possible to use a viewport to scale everything down? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://blog.xoppa.com/pixels

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood you but try setWorldSize method of viewport and select a higher resolution. For example: 
viewport.setWorldSize(1600,960);